# Async/await in combination with SubtleCrypto

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, redux

I noticed the following [example (last one)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest) on MDN which leads me to believe there's a way to assign the outcome of a SubtleCrypto function to a variable. But as far as I know/have researched about async/await it's only possible to use `await` inside the `async` function...

```
async function sha256(message) {
    const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(message);                     // encode as UTF-8
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);            // hash the message
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));                       // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join(''); // convert bytes to hex string
    return hashHex;
}

sha256('abc').then(hash => console.log(hash));

const hash = await sha256('abc');
```

Is the example incorrect or did I misinterpret something? And most importantly; is it possible to assign the outcome of a SubtleCrypto/Promise to a variable without `.then()`.

For those asking themselves why the hell I would need/want this. I'm playing around with WebCrypto in combination with redux-persist but it doesn't seem to handle Promise-based [transforms](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#transforms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is misleading (or incomplete), you cannot use `await` outside of `async function`s indeed. I have just edited it (MDN is a wiki!).

> Is it possible to assign the outcome of a SubtleCrypto/Promise to a variable without `.then()`.

Yes, that stores the promise object in the variable. To access the promises result, you need to use `then` or `await`.

Comment: Alright, I thought I was going crazy... Thanks for the clarifications. Looks like I'll have to dive into redux-persist then.